# How to set localization to ajax custom.js file ASP.Net Core 3.1?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

`services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");`

All text is translated with Resources files (.resx). I have no idea how to translate text inside of custom.js file which uses an ajax call.

```
$('.copy-gbt-to-clipboard').on("click", function () {

  var rowNumber = $(this).data('rownumber'); 
  var clickedElementID =  rowNumber;
  var Value = $(clickedElementID).text();

  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val(Value).select();

  $(clickedElementID_Value).append('<span class=" tooltiptext-selector_' + rowNumber + '">Copy</span>');
});
```

Comment: Is my answer helpful?If it is helpful,can you mark it as answer?Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

In controller,you can do like this:

```
 private readonly IHtmlLocalizer<xxxController> _localizer;
    
            public xxxController(IHtmlLocalizer<xxxController> localizer)
            {
                _localizer = localizer;
            }
public string GetData(string data)
        {
            return _localizer[data];
        }
```

ajax:

```
function getdata(){

    string data="xxxxxxx";
            $.ajax({
                url: 'GetData',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { data: data},
                success: function (data) {
                  var s=data;
                }
            });
        }
```